# How to TABLESAMPLE with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is it currently possible to `TABLESAMPLE` on some of the tables in an ORM query in SQLAlchemy?

The closest I could find is [`Query.suffix_with(*suffixes)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.suffix_with), but that places the suffix on the end of the query, rather than on the end of a table.

If it helps, this is my use case:

My query is currently:

```
query = session.query(A).options(
    subqueryload(A.rel1),
    subqueryload(A.rel2)
).filter(A.id >= min_id, A.id < max_id, [...])
```

and I would like to `TABLESAMPLE` on the table `A` so that I could efficiently load only a subset of `A` and their corresponding relations, with some filters. I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 as my database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update

[SQLAlchemy 1.1 and newer support `TABLESAMPLE`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3718) for selectables. `FromClause` elements have a method [`FromClause.tablesample()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.FromClause.tablesample) (think `Table`s) and [`sqlalchemy.tablesample()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tablesample) function can be used with all selectables, for example declarative model classes:

```
from sqlalchemy import tablesample, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

# Create an alias for A that uses SYSTEM sampling method (default)
a_sampled = aliased(A, tablesample(A, 2.5))

# Create an alias for A that uses BERNOULLI sampling method
a_bernoulli = aliased(A, tablesample(A, func.bernoulli(2.5)))
```

There's a slight asymmetry in that `tablesample(A, ...)`, where `A` is a declarative class, returns a `TableSample` from-clause, which has to be then aliased if used as a model. Otherwise it acts like a `FromClause`, e.g. the `Table` underlying the model class.

---

## Before

There seems to be [no discussion](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues?q=tablesample) about [`TABLESAMPLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) support at the time of writing this. As SQLAlchemy is very [extensible](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html), here's a very simple (read: may not work for all use cases) implementation of tablesample support:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql import Alias, FromClause
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased


class TableSample(Alias):

    __visit_name__ = 'tablesample'

    def __init__(self, selectable, argument=None, method=None,
                 seed=None):
        super(TableSample, self).__init__(selectable)
        self.method = method
        self.argument = argument
        self.seed = seed 


def tablesample(element, argument=None, method=None, seed=None):
    if isinstance(element, FromClause):
        return TableSample(element, argument=argument, method=method, seed=seed)
    else:
        return aliased(element, TableSample(element.__table__,
            argument=argument, method=method, seed=seed))


@compiles(TableSample)
def compile_tablesample(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    s = "%s TABLESAMPLE %s(%s)" % (
        compiler.visit_alias(element, **kwargs),
        element.method or 'SYSTEM',
        element.argument)

    if element.seed:
        s += " REPEATABLE (%s)" % compiler.process(element.seed, **kwargs)

    return s
```

The `argument` should be for the time being just a float representing a percentage between 0 and 100 for convenience, though PostgreSQL would accept any real-valued expression. The `seed` on the other hand is compiled and so literal python values have to be wrapped with [`literal()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal) or the like.

It should be used in similar fashion to [`aliased`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased):

```
a_sampled = tablesample(A, 2.5)

query = session.query(a_sampled).options(
    subqueryload(a_sampled.rel1),
    subqueryload(a_sampled.rel2)
).filter(a_sampled.id >= min_id, a_sampled.id < max_id, [...])
```

Comment: Thank you for writing sample code up too! I'd've been happy with a pointer, this just exceeds expectations.